# Скрыть элемент css при клике на гамбургер

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

как скрыть #fp-nav, когда гамбургер активен, и показать снова, когда гамбургер закрыт циклично? Я набросал немного и сделал функцию, она выполняет мою задачу, но единожды.
https://codepen.io/alexmillern/pen/KKPYpMO

```
$('.hamburger').click(function(){
    $('#fp-nav').hide();
    $('.hamburger').click(function(){
        $('#fp-nav').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.hamburger').click(function(){
    $('#fp-nav').toggle();    
    });
```